# iterating over specific directories in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, os.walk

I am trying to read directories within directories to gain access to specific files.

Now while I am able to go within all sub - directories to get the directories I want ( basically all directories with name 'sent' and 'inbox', I am unable to then go and open all the files within those folder.

```
 for root, dirs,  files in os.walk("/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402"):
    if len(dirs) != 0:
        for dir in dirs:
            if dir == "sent" or dir == "inbox":
                rootd = os.path.join(root,  dir)
                print rootd
                    #for root, dirs,  files in os.walk("/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/"+dir):
                for filename in files:
                    filename = os.path.join(rootd, filename)
                    print filename
                    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                        head,sub,authors,recipients = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(4)]
                        data=f.read()
```

Now I am able to read all the sub directories :

```
> /home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/farmer-d/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/williams-w3/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/symes-k/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lavorato-j/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lavorato-j/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/arnold-j/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/arnold-j/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lewis-a/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lewis-a/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/neal-s/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/neal-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/mcconnell-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/mcconnell-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/skilling-j/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/skilling-j/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/shankman-j/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/shankman-j/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/reitmeyer-j/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/ermis-f/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/ermis-f/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/kuykendall-t/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/kuykendall-t/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/hendrickson-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/scott-s/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/scott-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/carson-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/carson-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/causholli-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/bass-e/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/bass-e/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/cuilla-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/cuilla-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/geaccone-t/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/shapiro-r/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/shapiro-r/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/solberg-g/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/slinger-r/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/taylor-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/taylor-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/cash-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/cash-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/ward-k/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/ward-k/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/mann-k/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/mann-k/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/giron-d/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/giron-d/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/saibi-e/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/fossum-d/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/grigsby-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/grigsby-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/davis-d/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/davis-d/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/delainey-d/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/delainey-d/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/sturm-f/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/sturm-f/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/schoolcraft-d/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/germany-c/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/germany-c/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/stclair-c/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/horton-s/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/horton-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/keavey-p/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/keavey-p/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/dean-c/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/dean-c/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/bailey-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/benson-r/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/benson-r/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/pereira-s/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/pereira-s/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/sanchez-m/inbox
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lenhart-m/sent
/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/lenhart-m/inbox
```

But even though I do filename within files, I get nothing. Any pointers?

Comment: Use the [UniPath Module](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [`mailbox` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html)?

Comment: There is no need for `if len(dirs) != 0:`. If it is empty, the following `for dir in dirs:` will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You search for files only when the directory also contains directories. Your `for` loop for files should be at the same level than the test on the length of `dirs`

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/nandita/Downloads/enron_mail_20110402"):
    dir = os.path.basename(root)
    if dir == "sent" or dir == "inbox":
        print root
        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print filename
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                head,sub,authors,recipients = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(4)]
                data=f.read()
```